# run script in Angular

Tags: angular

Im using third party splitjs. script will search id of div then run, and it work great when i put element in index.html. But when i put element in component it seem script cant find id of elements? Im missing something?
Appreciate any comments.

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="red" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="blue" class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        Split(["#red", "#blue"], {
            minSize: 0
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-split/angular-split - have you looked into this? this is an angular wrapper for split.js

Comment: @SmokeyDawson yes i did, thanks man but i want to know why it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS: Posting as an answer, as the content is too long for a comment.

> **Why not working**

This is because you are running your script from `index.html` file only, whenever your application loads on the browser very first file which executes is index.html. Till that time neither of your application component gets loaded so script won't be able to find out elements.

> **How to make it work**

You can create one service and add this script code there and call that service after the initial component load, in that way it might be able to find DOM elements.

Comment: do we have another way to apply script for all component?

Comment: running a script in a service manner would do the trick i guess, try to make it shared service across the components.